# libtiff.net reading pixel data for image with 4 samples per pixel

Tags: c#, libtiff.net

currently I am trying to utilize libtiff.net library for processing digital Tiff images.
but the image that i have is not with standard ones.

the image contains **4 samples per pixel** and **10 bit per samples**.

my question is: how to read the value of each sample of a pixel.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no difference for the LibTiff.Net if you image is a 10 bits per sample or 8, or 16.

Some TIFF flavors can not be converted to RGBA using `ReadRGBAImage` method but the library should be able to decode them anyway.

Have a look at [Basic introduction to the capabilities of the library](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/help/articles/KB/basic-introduction.html) article. It contains enough information about different approaches to reading images.

In you case you might want to use `ReadScanline` or `ReadEncodedStrip` / `ReadEncodedTile` methods. Using these you should get decoded image data and then it is up to you how you will interpret the data.

You might want to check byte ordering, too. If you don't, you might end up with color channels in wrong order.